# Taking input and updating a div tag using javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

Ok so I have to make a basic javascript file that takes data from two input fields and then updates the div tag with the relevant new values when a button is clicked. This is the first thing I have ever done in JS, so excuse any bad practices. I have 3 buttons, the first two save and update only the name or the age respectively. The third one creates a new object "init" and saves and updates both. I wish I could tell you more about what is wrong, but nothing changes when I click any of the buttons so I have no idea.

Thanks for the help

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="inForm">
            <input type="text" name="user"/>
            <input type="text" name="age"/>
        </form>
    <button onClick="User.setName"> Save name </button>
    <button onClick="User.setAge"> Save age </button>
    <button onClick="writeIn"> Save </button>
    <div id="update">
    </div>
           <script language="JavaScript1.2" src="script.js" type="text/javascript"/>
    </body>

</html>
```

And here is my javascript:

```
var User = function() {
    var save = function(callback) {
        if (callback) {
            callback();
        }
    }

    return {
        name: function() {
            write = document.getElementById('update');
            write.innerHTML = this.name;
            return this.name;
        }(),
        age: function() {
            write = document.getElementById('update');
            write.innerHTML = this.age;
            return this.age;
        }(),
        setName: function() {
            this.name = document.inForm.name;
        },
        setAge: function() {
            this.age = document.inForm.age;
        },
        save: save,
        init: function(name, age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            write = document.getElementById('update');
            write.innerHTML = this.age + this.name;
            return this;
        }
    };
};

function writeIn() {
    var a = new User
    a.init(document.inForm.name, document.inForm.age)
}

console.log(a.name, b.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function changeText2(){
        var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
        document.getElementById('boldStuff2').innerHTML = userInput;
     }
    </script>
    <p>Welcome to the site <b id='boldStuff2'>dude</b> </p> 
    <input type='text' id='userInput' value='Enter Text Here' />
    <input type='button' onclick='changeText2()' value='Change Text'/>
```

I think you are missing in your function to select by id the user inputs. Just trying to help you but not sure.
I took the example from http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php/

Answer (score 0):

To call a function, you must put parentheses after it, e.g.

```
<button onClick="User.setName()"> Save name </button>
```

Also, I think all the references to `name` in the Javascript should be `user`.